# Error while Connecting salesforce via node

Tags: node.js, salesforce

I am trying to connect salesforce api from node and using nforce package for the same. Initially I have established the oauth authentication successfully. While trying to interact with the salesforce components I am getting the below error while sending the request for "/account" route. Could any one please help me on this.

**/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/nforce/index.js:905
      opts.oauth.instance_url,
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance_url' of undefined
    at Connection._apiRequest (/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/nforce/index.js:905:17)
    at Connection._queryHandler (/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/nforce/index.js:674:8)
    at Connection.query (/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/nforce/index.js:618:15)
    at /opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/server.js:51:11
    at Object.resolve (/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/nforce/lib/promises.js:25:20)
    at /opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/nforce/index.js:301:16
    at Object.resolve (/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/nforce/lib/promises.js:25:20)
    at Request._callback (/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/nforce/index.js:863:23)
    at Request.self.callback (/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request. (/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage. (/opt/test_node/node-sf-connection/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)**

Please find the below code snippet which I tried.

```
var express = require('express');
var nforce = require('nforce');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
console.log("Trying to establish the connection");
var org = nforce.createConnection({
    clientId : "################################",
    clientSecret : "############################",
    redirectUri : "https://login.salesforce.com/login/callback"
});

var oauth;
org.authenticate({ username: '!!!!!!!!!!!!', password: '!!!!!!!!!'}, function(err, resp){
    console.log("authentication established");
  // store the oauth object for this user 
  if(!err) {
    oauth = resp;
    console.log("Authentication established successfully");
    console.log(oauth);
  }else{
    console.log(err);
  }
});
var q = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account';
app.get('/account',function(req,res){
  console.log("Fetching the account from salesforce");
  org.query({ query: q }, function(err, resp){

  if(!err && resp.records) {
  console.log('It worked');
  console.log("total : " + resp.totalSize);
  console.log("fetched : " + resp.records.length);

    var acc = resp.records[0];
    acc.set('Name', 'Really Spiffy Cleaners');
    acc.set('Industry', 'Cleaners');

    org.update({ sobject: acc, oauth: oauth }, function(err, resp){
      if(!err) console.log('It worked!');
    });

  }else{
    console.log('error');
    console.log(err);
  }
});

});
var port = process.env.PORT || 3001; // set our port
console.log("Started");
app.listen(port);
console.log('port ' + port); // shoutout to the user
```